# Configure selinux to allow snmpd to read to a custom location

Tags: snmp, selinux

I have snmpd executing a script under /custom/location/myscript.sh. If I disable selinux all works well. If I enable selinux it stops working and if I do an audit2why I see the following:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1371990300.064:23445): avc:  denied  { read open } for  pid=21423 comm="snmpd" name="myscript.sh" dev=dm-0 ino=1046532 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:snmpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=file

    Was caused by:
            Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

            You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.

type=AVC msg=audit(1371990313.066:23446): avc:  denied  { read open } for  pid=21425 comm="snmpd" name="myscript.sh" dev=dm-0 ino=1046532 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:snmpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=file

    Was caused by:
            Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

            You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

If I do an ls -Z /custom/location I see the following:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 myscript.sh
```

So I need to do an chcon-R on the directory. I tried:

```
chcon -R -u unconfined_u -r system_r -t snmpd_t /custom/location
```

Only to get the following error:

```
chcon: failed to change context of `myscript.sh' to `unconfined_u:system_r:snmpd_t:s0': Permission denied
```

I also tried using audit2allow to create a custom policy but that didn't seem to work.

I really don't want to disable selinux. Can anyone assist me in understanding how I can allow snmpd the ability to read from /custom/location?

Thanks
Brad

Since the output was so long I am truncating a bit - but here's the results of ausearch:

```
----
time->Sun Jun 23 08:27:13 2013
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1371990433.731:23453): arch=c000003e syscall=189 success=no            
exit=-13 a0=11760e0 a1=3e50616319 a2=1178ef0 a3=21 items=0 ppid=20865 pid=21434 auid=0 
uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=3863 comm="chcon"
exe="/usr/bin/chcon" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=   
(null)

type=AVC msg=audit(1371990433.731:23453): avc:  denied  { relabelto } for  pid=21434  
comm="chcon" name="scripts" dev=dm-0 ino=1046530 
scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 
tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:snmpd_t:s0 tclass=dir
----
time->Sun Jun 23 08:27:24 2013
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1371990444.075:23454): arch=c000003e syscall=59 success=no     
exit=-13 a0=7fdb8933c6d0 a1=7fdb8933c3a0 a2=7fff16ef1790 a3=1f items=0 ppid=18001 
pid=21435 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) 
ses=3765 comm="snmpd" exe="/usr/sbin/snmpd" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:snmpd_t:s0 key=
(null)

type=AVC msg=audit(1371990444.075:23454): avc:  denied  { read open } for  pid=21435 
comm="snmpd" name="snmp.sh" dev=dm-0 ino=1046532 
scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:snmpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 
tclass=file
----
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ausearch -m avc -ts today` to your question.

Comment: Will do in a moment (that output a TON of stuff)

Comment: Added some of the output above - there were way more entries but they look repetitive.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [you probably don't need to write a custom module at all](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/63137.html).

I would place the script in one of the places SELinux expects to find executables, to start with, and only if that is not possible, using the output of `audit2allow` (and not `audit2why`, which gives a human friendly message, but is less useful in terms of understanding the real problem), I'd analyze the AVC denial.

Changing the security context of a file is a privileged operation, and you gave no clue with regards to which user you tried to execute that command with. Use `root`.

Note, however, that the proper thing to do is not to `chcon` the file, because that won't persist after a system relabel, but to use `semanage` to add a a security context to the path:

```
semanage fcontext -a type_enforcement "/path/expression(/.*)?"
```

Check the output of `semanage fcontext -l | less` for a first impression on how a path expression should look like.

For a deeper understanding of the problem, you need to know which contexts the `snmpd` daemon is allowed to transition to. You can find help in the `seinfo` and  `sesearch` manpages.

The upstream source code of the [`refpolicy`](http://oss.tresys.com/projects/refpolicy/wiki/DownloadRelease) can be checked in order to learn what would be the correct label for an executable to be read by an `snmpd_t` labeled file. A probably better idea is to download the source policy matching the policy version in use in your OS using your package manager.

[This](https://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/hardened/selinux/selinux-handbook.xml?part=2&chap=5) is a good resource to understand the function of the different files (esp. 5b) involved in a module.

First check the file contexts defined for this module (this is what you'll find using `semanage fcontext -l | grep snmp`, more or less):

```
# cat refpolicy/policy/modules/contrib/snmp.fc
/etc/rc\.d/init\.d/((snmpd)|(snmptrapd))        --      gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_initrc_exec_t,s0)

/usr/sbin/snmptrap      --      gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_exec_t,s0)
/usr/sbin/snmptrapd     --      gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_exec_t,s0)

/usr/share/snmp/mibs/\.index    --      gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_var_lib_t,s0)

/var/agentx(/.*)?       gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_var_lib_t,s0)
/var/net-snmp(/.*)      gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_var_lib_t,s0)

/var/lib/net-snmp(/.*)? gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_var_lib_t,s0)
/var/lib/snmp(/.*)?     gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_var_lib_t,s0)

/var/log/snmpd\.log.*   --      gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_log_t,s0)

/var/run/net-snmpd(/.*)?        gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_var_run_t,s0)
/var/run/snmpd(/.*)?    gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_var_run_t,s0)
/var/run/snmpd\.pid     --      gen_context(system_u:object_r:snmpd_var_run_t,s0)
```

Then, the type enforcement rules defined here (snippet):

```
# head -22 refpolicy/policy/modules/contrib/snmp.te
policy_module(snmp, 1.14.0)

########################################
#
# Declarations
#

type snmpd_t;
type snmpd_exec_t;
init_daemon_domain(snmpd_t, snmpd_exec_t)

type snmpd_initrc_exec_t;
init_script_file(snmpd_initrc_exec_t)

type snmpd_log_t;
logging_log_file(snmpd_log_t)

type snmpd_var_run_t;
files_pid_file(snmpd_var_run_t)

type snmpd_var_lib_t;
files_type(snmpd_var_lib_t)
```

And finally, the interface (`snmp.if`), file.

With this information at hand, you need to find out what would be the right context for `snmpd` to be able to **execute** a script, and then, manually add a context rule to the path where the executable will be.

Comment: I'd rather not copy the script to a location that SELinux already expects to find executable. Simply because its a custom/inhouse script and we tend to centralize those in a certain location for backup and management reasons. So for instance we put them under /ourcompany/scripts/name.sh that way they're easily found by everyone. If I go stick it in some obscure location no one's going to think to move that to a new server if/when we retire the existing server.

Comment: As far as running semanage fcontext I tried  semanage fcontext -a -t snmpd_t "/ourcompany/scripts/.*"  but that returns /usr/sbin/semanage: Type snmpd_t is invalid, must be a file or device type. I must admit I'm an selinux newbie and I'm really fumbling around in the dark. I tried looking at semanage fcontext -l | less but I'm not sure what I should be looking at. Any more pointers?